# How to emit signals with an interval in Qt?

Tags: qt, events, timer

I'm writing a simple port communication program. On the GUI side of the application I have a panel with 12 buttons that send signals to the parallel port interface. The communication with the port is done and working. What I need now is an automatic switching between buttons. The goal is to start kind of screensaver that will periodically activate the buttons and send signals to the port. In practice it would look like this: a timer is started for 2 minutes and if any event occurs it is restarted. Otherwise if timer reaches `timeout()` the qt signal is emitted, the switching begins and the buttons are automatically `click()`'ed with the interval of 5 seconds.

My questions are:

- How to enable a starting timer that will be reseted if any key/mouse event occurs?
- How to define a transition between the buttons with a sleep interval?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`QTimer`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtimer.html) for the timing part.

For the "screen-saver"-like one, create a single-shot timer, connect it to a custom slot of yours, and set it's interval to two minutes.

```
activeTimer = new QTimer(this);
activeTimer->setInterval(2*60*1000);
activeTimer->setSingleShot(true);
connect(activeTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(activateAutoClick()));
activeTimer->start();
```

In that custom slot, start a second, non-single shot timer connected to a second custom slot

```
void YourThing::activateAutoClick() {
  autoTimer->setInterval(5*1000);
  autoTimer->setSingleShot(false);
  connect(autoTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(autoClick()));
  autoTimer->start();
}
```

And do whatever you want in terms of sending signals to your port in `autoClick`.

To cancel either timer, simply call their `stop()` method/slot.

To implement the "screen-saver" behavior, create a function that:

1. Calls `autoTimer->stop()` to disable auto clicks
2. Calls `activeTimerr->start(2*60*1000)` to restart that one

And call that function whenever needed. You can do that from already existing slots for your buttons, or reimplement event handlers like [`QWidget`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#mouseMoveEvent)'s `mouseMoveEvent`, `keyPressedEvent` and such. (Be sure to read the documentation for the handlers, some require specific preparation.)